# Enable X button in OutputProgressPage

Tags: inno-setup

the Abort (x button) on the OutputProgressPage is disabled, i want to allow the user to abort when on the OutputProgressPage  is there any way to enable the button?

[image]

Comment: I tried it and as you mentioned it's not working for -`OutputProgressPage`

Comment: If you enable the close system menu item, it won't do anything, because it requires the cancel button to be able to receive focus (which means that you would have to show and enable the cancel button). Then you will need some flag variable that will hold the fact that the setup has been cancelled (to interrupt your progress work).

Comment: I've enabled the CancelButton for my OutputProgressPage  - 
`procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);

begin
  case CurPageID of
 ProgressPage.ID:
    begin
 WizardForm.CancelButton.Visible := True;
 WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;
    end;`

 i see the Cancel button but still the X button is grayed out

Comment: Sure, the close menu item requires the cancel button focusable to even do something. But there is no event which would synchronize the menu item state with the button's state again (so it's not enough to show the cancel button to enable that menu item). That menu item you'll need to enable by yourself; [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/YB45THc4) will enable the close system menu item and allow you to cancel the setup with it. But a more difficult part will be to determine the setup has been cancelled.

Comment: 10X Tlama, it helped!